# Data not getting stored in table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have generated a migration to add a status field in fundings table by using rails generate migration add_status_to_fundings. migration file gets created and in it, I have added
**add_column :fundings, :status, :string**
Then **rails db:migrate**
in schema **status** gets added to the funding table. but whatever data I enter in status it doesn't get stored in the funding table. neither the data display in show.html.erb file. kindly help.

_form.html.erb

```
<div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :status %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :status %>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= form.submit "Apply", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
</div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><strong>Status: </strong><%= @funding.status %></p><br>
```

migrationfile

```
class AddStatusToFundings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :fundings, :status, :string
  end
end
```

rails console

```
<Funding id: 1, describe_activity: "10 players in each team", type_of_activity: "Cricket", season: "Fall", activity_details: "best outdoor games ", name_of_organisation: "BCCI", activity_start_date: "2018-12-12", number_of_weeks: "6", days_per_week: "6", hours_per_day: "6", program_registration_cost: 100, family_contribution: "10", other_funds: 20, other_fund_provider: "Arni", amount_requested: 70, created_at: "2018-05-23 17:56:03", updated_at: "2018-05-23 17:56:03", child_id: 1, status: nil>
```

Comment: Have you included `:status` in the permitted parameters in your controller?

Comment: for the status field I want to make it a dropdown and want it pending for user and only admin can change it to approved or declined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the problem you have is not with the table itself. you just forget to add :status to your permitted parameters.

maybe you have something like this in your controller

```
private
  def funding_params
    params.require(:funding).permit(:describe_activity, :type_of_activity..., :status)
  end
```

just add :status there to be permitted